# Fixed effects model negative adjusted R-squared

Tags: r, statistics, fixed, effects

I am writing my thesis and I am very new to panel data analysis and to r.
I have a panel dataset with about 200 entries over 10 years. The model is as follows:
schoolpercentage ~neighborhood percentage + schooldensity+ religious or not
I've saved my data as a pdata.frame and conducted some tests to pick between fixed, random or pooled effects.

```
cdata<-pdata.frame(NOAtroto, index = c("Kolom1", "JAAR"))
```

Kolom1 is the unit number and JAAR is the year

```
pool<- plm(SCHOOLPERC~WIJKPERC+isreligious+withinkm, data = cdata, model = 'pooling')

fixed<-plm(cdata$SCHOOLPERC~cdata$WIJKPERC+cdata$isreligious+cdata$withinkm, data=cdata, model = 

'within')
random<-plm(cdata$SCHOOLPERC~cdata$WIJKPERC+cdata$isreligious+cdata$withinkm, data=cdata, model = 'random')
#pick between pooled OLS and random effects model
plmtest(pool)
#pooled OLS and fixed effects
pFtest(fixed, pool)
#Hausman test 
phtest(fixed, random)
```

According to these, a fixed effects model would be superior. However, when I run 'fixed' the adjusted r-squared comes out negative, while the variables are shown to be significant. None of the other models return a negative value, while they do return coefficients of similar sizes.
Does this mean that the fixed effects model is inappropriate for my data structure? Are there any alternatives that I have not explored yet, or modifications I need to make? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like one for crossvalidated, I think.

Comment: @dash2 thanks ill move it!